# Generate Open API Spec from Model/Controller Metadata in Loopback4

Tags: node.js, typescript, decorator, loopback, openapi

Does **Loopback4** provide a way to generate an Open Api Spec from decorated models and controllers?

If not, is there a way to access controllers and models metadata at runtime?

Answer (score 1):

Noticed just now that the server object exposes the getApiSpec method which returns an OpenApiSpec object.

```
export class MyController {
    constructor(
        @inject('application.instance') private app: Application,
        @inject('rest.http.request') private req: ServerRequest) { }

    @get('/spec')
    async api(): Promise<OpenApiSpec> {
        const server = await this.app.getServer(RestServer);
        return server.getApiSpec();
    }
}
```

**EDIT: This solution doesn't solve the problem completely**

The api spec returned by `server.getApiSpec()` doesn't contain information about the models.

Answer (score 0):

After you started the LoopBack 4 application (assuming you did not change the REST server port), go to http://localhost:3000/openapi.json, you'll get the OpenAPI spec.